# Detect presence of stand alone "<" or ">" symbols in string that contains HTML tags

Tags: html

For example, I have a string like

`"This is a <b> Sample </b> string with characters < 100"`

My user will include html tags like `<b>`,`<div>` etc. They are allowed. I need to detect and identify the position of only the stand alone "<" and ">" symbols for some other validation. It is a c#.net project.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
/<[^\w/]|[^\w]>/
```

This would search for a < without a letter or / efter it and a > without a letter before it. Should suffice in most cases.